# Python while loop closing console

Tags: python, loops, console

My console is closing every time I start the loop and I don't get why...

```
index = ""  
while not index:
    index = int(input("Enter the index that you want: "))
```

Comment: Just which error message, if any are you getting? Include the full traceback. And what do you mean by your console closing? Also, edit the code shown so it can run. Right now the indentation is off.

Comment: I'm assuming it's because `""` evaluates to `False` in Python and so you never enter the loop.

Comment: @MattCremeens: no, `index = ""` evaluates to False, hence `not index` is True, so we enter the loop

Comment: @smci You're right. The double negative threw me. :)

Comment: it works for me

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that your loop is executing only once and is exiting after that (*that's what I can think of based on your code*).

**The reason is:** at the start, your index is `""`. Hence `not index` is evaluated as `True` since python considers empty string as `False`. But within the loop you are assigning value to the index. Hence, in the next run `not index` is returning `False`.

Below is the sample on how ti works:

```
>>> index = "" 
>>> not index
True  <--- True since string is empty
>>> index = 3
>>> not index  
False <--- False since string is having some value
```

Answer (score 0):

a) your code seems fine.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> index=""
>>> while not index:
...     index=int(input("blabla: "))
... 
blabla: 2
>>> print(index)
2
```

Or with python 3:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> index=""
>>> while not index:
...     index=int(input("bla: "))
... 
bla: 4
>>> print(index)
4
```

b) My console is closing: This seems to be the actual problem. Can you specify your operating system and terminal? How did you invoke the python interpreter? I guess you are on Windows? Start a console by hitting windowskey+r and type "cmd", then run python from there to see the output.